# .NET Windows Service - What is the most efficient method for triggering an action upon database record creation?

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, service

I have several different applications, mostly ASP.NET web apps, that generate pending email database records.

Every minute, I fire an executable with a windows task to clear out the pending email buffer.

My goal is to shorten this one-minute interval to one-second.

I intend to use a windows service.

**Is there a better method than simply polling the pending-email database table every second?**

While I'm sure MSSQL can handle a transaction every second for eternity, it does not feel like an ideal solution for an application that may only send 80 emails in a day.

Comment: Perhaps there is some shared cache solution that is easy to implement? I could dump a record into cache in parallel to writing the DB record. Perhaps there is a way to trigger the sending service using an actual SQL Server Trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is 100% perfect. You can use windows service or you can  use the windows scheduler to schedule the high frequency job.

If you are implementing the cache here. Unnecessary increasing the implementation which is not required. I would suggest you keep the implementation as is which means polling job with 1 second frequency.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server already has the necessary infrastructure to do this, via the [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) procedure. In your code, instead of populating the pending email table, call `sp_send_dbmail` instead and let SQL Server drive the mail delivery.

`sp_send_dbmail` is based in turn on [Service Broker Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If you don't want to use DBMail you can leverage directly the activation mechanism which allows you to monitor a queue for messages, in a non polling fashion. With activation you will have almost instantaneous latency (sub second) w/o having to poll for changes every second.